# Возврат значения из JS функции в CefSharp.Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

Пытаюсь возвратить значение JS функции на странице, загруженной в CEF браузере, используя метод **EvaluateScriptAsync**. Посетил десятки веб-страниц и документаций, однако работы скрипта добиться так и не смог.
При отладке значение response всегда null.

**Отрывок кода программы:**

```
private void OnLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args)
{
    //Wait for the Page to finish loading
    if (args.IsLoading == false)
    {
        const string script = @"(function()
                {
                    alert(123);
                    return 1 + 1;
                })();";

        chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script).ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            var response = x.Result;

            if (response.Result != null)
            {
                var onePlusOne = response.Result;
                val = (string)onePlusOne.ToString();
                chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("alert('" + val + "')"); // тут скрипт возвращает алерт в браузере со значением 2, это значит что js скрипт полностью корректен
                all.Add(val);
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

Каким образом все-таки верно записать полученное значение в переменную, или, например, в коллекцию C#?

Answer (score 0):

Так здесь, похоже, сам скрипт виноват. Нужно обернуть в функцию, и чтобы был return.

Насчет самого вызова, я вот так делал (да, синхронно, но все равно же все эти операции не вызывать в UI-потоке):

```
public object EvalJS(string code)
{
    var task = cwb.GetBrowser().MainFrame.EvaluateScriptAsync(code);
    task.Wait();

    if (task.Result.Success)
    {
        return task.Result.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new CefJsException(task.Result.Message); // CefJsException - это мой собственный класс, можете заменить Exception просто
    }
}
```